# Use wxWidget to create a rectangle area with relief

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have recently begun to use wxWidget, it is a very powerfull GUI API and from now I want to create some rectangles with relief flags like: "flat", "raised", "sunken" and so on but I don't see any things in the website guide at http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classes.html#letter_T which I can use to realise this customize widwget.
Somebody can help me??

Comment: This seems to be two questions.  One about relief ( raised, sunken ) and one about some code that does not show a window when you expect.  It is best to ask just one question at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two kinds of windows, toplevel windows that appear by themselves, and child windows that appear inside, or at least 'belong' to another window.  Every window except a toplevel windows should have a parent.

The window you have created does not have a parent and is not a toplevel window.  You should first create a wxFrame, which is a toplevel window, before you create any other windows.

You should take a look at the sample applications, in particular the one called 'mimimal' which shows how to code an application that behaves nicely.  Once you understand how that works, you can modify the sample code to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I'm goingo to do what you have said

Comment: I thank that the fact to put "NULL" has parent for a wxWindow defined it as a Toplevel window but for now I know that is false.

Answer (score 0):

The wxWindow class supports the following styles:

wxBORDER_DEFAULT: The window class will decide the kind of border to show, if any.

wxBORDER_SIMPLE: Displays a thin border around the window.

wxSIMPLE_BORDER is the old name for this style.

wxBORDER_SUNKEN: Displays a sunken border.

wxSUNKEN_BORDER is the old name for this style.

wxBORDER_RAISED: Displays a raised border.

wxRAISED_BORDER is the old name for this style.

Details of these and many more can be found at 
http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why but wxWindow doesn't itself. I use the Show(true) method of wxWindow but nothing is displayed on my screen.

Comment: You are going to have to provide more info if you want people to help you.  Post your code, and explain what you intended it to do and what actually happens.

Comment: My first idea it was making a wxgrid which could contain some wxListbox or wxButton in some of its cells but this is not possible, wxGrid is intended for data not window or control in general case so another idea appeared to me. With wxSizer like wxFlexGridSizer I can make a virtual which contains wxTexctrl for text entry and others controls like wxButton but I have a big problem now because like a wxGrid, I want to put on the top of my wxFlexGridSizer multiple raised area and each of them with its own label.

Comment: Each raised area has to represent one column in my wxFlexGridSizer this is why I'm looking for something like a canvas with attribute like "raised", "sunken", "flat" and so on something very similar to canvas's properties on tkinter (python).

Comment: Please edit your question so that it is clear what it is you are asking.

Comment: I want to know if it is possible to make this multiple raised area, the same like the top of columns or rows in a wxGrid but for a wxFlexGridSizer for example. If it is possible what should I read for achieve that.

Comment: Look at this picture: http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxGrid%20Manual   the raised area for me is those on which you can see this labels: "teValue2", "Current Colour", "dateValue2" etc... I want to make such raised areas but in wxFlexGridSizer. So is there a way to do that?? I have no idea for do that.

Comment: From the stackoverflow FAQ: If other users ask you for more information in the comments, edit your question using the edit link just below your original question.